How to implement Display for a trait
I would like a trait X to implement the Display trait so that it's available for all structs that implement X.
How can I do ?
Thanks !
I tried this but got an error (in main()) :
use std::fmt;

pub trait MyTrait {
    fn get_value(&self) -> i32;
}

impl fmt::Display for dyn MyTrait {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        write!(f, "{}", self.get_value())
    }
}

pub struct MyStruct {
    value: i32,
}

impl MyTrait for MyStruct {
    fn get_value(&self) -> i32 {
        self.value
    }
}

fn main() {
    let my_struct = MyStruct { value: 42 };
    println!("{}", my_struct); // `MyStruct` cannot be formatted with the default formatter
}


In the println!-line, mystruct is a MyStruct, which is not the same as dyn MyTrait for which you provided a Display-impl (even if it could be). If you change println!("{}", mystruct); to println!("{}", &mystruct as &dyn MyTrait) it'll work.

Thank you, it works. I'm new to Rust, this is a subtlety I didn't know.

The statement you want to implement is "every type that implements the trait MyTrait should also implement the trait Display, as follows ...". In Rust, this is naturally expressed as follows
impl<T: MyTrait> fmt::Display for T {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        write!(f, "{}", self.get_value())
    }
}

You should read the impl<T: MyTrait> part as exactly "implement this for every type T that implements MyTrait".

Except this won't compile either due to the orphan rules

Indeed, I get a "type parameter T must be used as the type parameter for some local type" error. In my example, no T is used; I guess this is the reason why... Thanks anyway.
